# Changing subfigure for subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, cls

I have a `cls` file with the following lines using the `subfigure` package:

```
\RequirePackage[FIGBOTCAP,TABBOTCAP]{subfigure}
\RequirePackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\parskip}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.9em}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3.1em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{3.7em}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3.0em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\arial}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure (\alph{subfigure})}
\renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure:\space}
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
```

I would like to change it for `subcaption` package.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: The easiest change is to replace \subfigure with \subfloat (also supported by the subcaption package).  They both use the same subfigure counter.  (Not sure about p@subfigure.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I tried to use the 'subcaption' package, but it has conflict with 'subfigure', which I need to define the lines with \cft, e.g. '''\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}'''.
I am already using 'subfloat' with 'subfig'', but I am also maintaining 'subfigure', so there is no error when compiling the mentioned lines

Comment: I thought you were going to replace the obsolete and buggy subfigure package with subcaption.  There is no way to make them compatible.  BTW, subcaption is not compatible with subfig, but you don't need it either.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thai is the idea, but since I coudl not solve it, I am using `subfig`. I m aware they are compatible

Comment: Well, if you ever come up with an MWE you want to implement using subcaption, let me know.  OTOH, I never use tocloft (overly complicated and not needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adopting the following:

```
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

instead of

```
\RequirePackage[FIGBOTCAP,TABBOTCAP]{subfigure}
\RequirePackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
```

Why is that?

The `subfigure` option for `tocloft` is only required when the `subfigure` package is used. If that is not the case, as it was here, one should use the default `tocloft` option which is `titles` (see [`tocloft` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)).
By doing that, there is no more conflict between `subcaption` and `subfigure`, and one may use the former package without difficulties.

The following part is dedicated to changing the label format. As I do not want it, I simply comment. (I wish I know how to modify it for `subcaption`!)

```
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure (\alph{subfigure})}
%\renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure:\space}
%\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
```

And all the rest

```
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\large \arial \bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\parskip}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.9em}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3.1em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{3.7em}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3.0em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\arial}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\arial}
```

works fine!